# Zooms events in Polymer Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polymer

I am working on an app that will dynamically load in markers based on a users location.  The map should add events to the map if a user zooms out. For the map we are using Polymer's Google Map.  I am having a hard time finding out how to react to the zoom event.  We added a map to the page with:

`<google-map latitude="45" longitude="-73" zoom="15" mouseEvents="true" clickEvents="true"></google-map>`

I have tried several different js eventhandlers such as:

```
<script>
var map = document.querySelector("google-map");
console.log(map);
map.addEventListener("bounds_changed", function() {
alert(map.zoom);
});
</script>
```

I can't even get events such as "google-map-click" to fire.  The only one that seems to work is "google-map-ready".

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding event listener to `map` property instead of `google-map` element.

Something like this gives you all zoom changes

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var mapElement = document.querySelector("google-map");
    mapElement.addEventListener('api-load', function(e) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        // handle zoom event...
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: how do i get access to the `google` namespace within a component?